# How to verify a password in php which was inserted into the database through manual hashing by mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to verify the password through `php` that is inserted into mysql database via it's own hashing method?

For example, if I manually insert a user data in a table, suppose- `users` table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, pswd) VALUES ('demo@example.com', SHA1('pass123'));
```

And let us assume the hashed password inside mysql database is:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| pswd                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
| AAFDC23870ECBCD3D557B6423A8982134E17927E |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I want to use `php` to create a login form and when user will insert the credentials they should be able to log in. I mean, there will not be any php registration form for users; passwords will be provided manually. But how can I verify the user provided data in `php` against the password stored in the `mysql` database?

As far as I know, the `password_verify()` in php only works when the password is hashed using its own `password_hash()` function.

I have found another solution, that is to use sql query again, like this-

```
SELECT pswd FROM users WHERE email='$_POST["email"]' AND pswd = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

And then by counting the resultset for any row return from executing that mysql query and thus verify. But, this seems to me a very bad approach. I don't know whether there is any other way or not. There must have some good approach to solve this issue. Or, may be I have to use another php form to insert the data into the database.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can use the [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) in php to create the hash from the password the user provides, and compare it to the hash stored for `demo@example.com`.

Comment: But, isn't it like, if I would have hashed the password using `sha1` from inside `php` then, that would be matched. But as the hash is created using `mysql`, can it be verified using `sha1()` of `php`. Sorry, I don't have much knowledge about hashing algorithms.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use password_hash() and store the resulting hash in the database.

```
INSERT INTO users SET email=?, pswd=?
```

If you need to insert a password manually, you can use a quick command-line PHP script to convert it to a hash. For example:

```
<?php echo password_hash($ARGV[1], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n"; ?>
```

Use this string when you manually insert the password to your database using phpmyadmin or mysql client.

It's a good idea to avoid putting your password into a literal string in an SQL query, even if you hash it using an SQL function. Keep in mind the whole SQL string — *unhashed* — is logged in the query log and the binary log.

Later, when validating a login, fetch the password hash like this:

```
SELECT pswd FROM users WHERE email=?
```

Then your PHP code has the hash. You can use password_verify().

P.S.: Please learn to use parameterized queries and do not use $_POST variables in your SQL queries. That's an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. But maybe you haven't understood me properly. The insert query I have mentioned is used outside php, I mean using `phpmyadmin` or `mysql console`. But I want to verify the password from within php. That's why I am facing problem

Comment: @RakibulIslam — Don't do that. Write a command line PHP program or an admin page instead.

Comment: @Quentin Sure, thanks. I was also thinking about that. But I guessed the thing I wanted is possible with security.

Comment: See my edit above with advice for manually entering passwords.

Answer (score 4):

If we manually insert users and hashed passwords

```
INSERT INTO (username, password) VALUES ('humpty',SHA1('dumpty') )
```

Then we do the same thing to perform a verification, in a SELECT statement

```
SELECT u.username
  FROM users u
 WHERE u.username = :uname            
   AND u.password = SHA1( :pword )

$sth->bindValue(':uname','humpty');
$sth->bindValue(':pword','dumpty');
```

If we get a row back, then the username and password matched.

---

(Note that we're using prepared statement with bind placeholders; if for some unfathomable reason we can't do that, then at a minimum, potentially unsafe values incorporated into SQL next must be properly escaped. If we don't mitigate SQL Injection vulnerabilities, then we leave our app wide open to login attempts

```
$username = 'humpty'' OR 1=1 -- ';
$password = 'doesntmatter';
```

---

SHA-1 isn't the best choice for password hashes, it's computationally inexpensive. It would be better (more cryptographically secure) to use a more computationally expensive hash algoritm, such as bcrypt.

Somewhere the question jumped the rails, and added an MD5 function as a password hash. We should not consider MD5 suitable for password hashes. Ever.

Comment: Sorry, in my example, that was MD5 somehow, I've edited :) BTW, Thanks for your answer. Yes, SHA1 is vulnerable now a days, but as I was trying to insert the data manually inside the database, that's why I used SHA1. I guess I can't use bcrypt in mysql.

Comment: @RakibulIslam: there is no builtin bcrypt hash function in MySQL (at least as of 5.7). A better pattern would be to generate the hash in the application, and store the hash value in the database, instead of using MySQL builtin SHA1 (or SHA2) hash algorithm.  I attempted to answer the question that was asked...  "If we have already manually inserted rows using MySQL builtin SHA1 hash..." then how do we do a "check" of a user password hash from php?  (I concur with Bill Karwins comments and advice.)